# How to create online database for my blog app?

Tags: android, database

I want to create an android app for my blog.
What I want is that the users should able to refresh the app to see the latest posts.
What can I do for that?
I have thought of 2 possible ideas:
1.) If somehow the app could connect to the blog directly and pick up content, then that would be great
2.) Otherwise, maybe I can create some online database of articles which the app can pick up

The blog is a textual blog (no images involved).
I have no idea of either of the 2 methods I mentioned above. I know basic android programming but I am not much familiar with database management.
Can someone guide me how to implement either of the above methods?
Also, it would be great if someone could share a useful link on how to learn database management specifically for android.

Edit: Thank you for your answers. I came to know that Google provides ready-made RSS feed for the blog which I directly used to build my app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a database, unless you are wanting users to login/sign up or add content in some way.

If they are strictly reading what you post, you can write your app's code to retrieve data from the URL that your blog is posted to, the same way a news app updates its information. If you run your blog through a Google owned website, Google provides tools to do this. Otherwise there are some extra steps in your app code.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a HTTP API to support your app interactions, something like:

- Retrieve post information
- Comment
- etc...

You shouldn't access the database directly from an app, because your blog server should define the business rules and it's easier to fix a bug in a web server than deploying another release in the app store.